# How to redefine c++ macro with reduced parameters?

Tags: c++, macros

I have following macros in an existing project,

```
#define TRACE1(attr,str,...)   REL_LOG(attr, str, ##_VA_ARGS__)
#define TRACE2(str,...)       REL_LOG(str, ##_VA_ARGS__)
```

And they have been used like,

```
TRACE1(1, "hello %s", "world");
TRACE2("[prefix] hello %s", "world");
```

Now I need to transform the TRACE1 macro to TRACE2 macro so that attr param will be avoided. I dont want to touch all the places where TRACE1 has been called for purpose. I did something like,

```
#undef TRACE1
#define TRACE1(str, ...) TRACE2(str,...)
```

However, getting following compiler error, // in second line

> error: expected primary-expression before '...' token

Comment: If you don't want to change all the current places that `TRACE1` is used, won't that cause the parameters where `TRACE1` is used to be incorrect/misaligned for the new `TRACE1` function-like macro?

Comment: @Eljay thats true. I am doing it temporary for debugging purpose. I wont commit the change.

Comment: @Jarod42 I did follow your suggestion but got compilers error. See updated post.

Comment: Works in gcc, clang and MSVC? https://godbolt.org/z/6Y67GTGd6. All three complain about your original code https://godbolt.org/z/E986E5WYb

Comment: Probably my project is configured to fail on warning. Worked with `#define TRACE1(attr, str, ...) TRACE2(str, ##__VA_ARGS__)` @AlanBirtles

Comment: please post a [mre] rather than snippets

Comment: @AlanBirtles the `##` needs to be dropped when passing from one macro to another. You don't want the 1st macro to stringify the values to the 2nd macro, you want to pass the actual values: `#define TRACE1(attr, str, ...) TRACE2(str, __VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was just pasting the code from the question to show that `#undef TRACE1` is correct and `#undef TRACE1(attr, str, ...)` isn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have `...` as parameter, in the associated text you must use `__VA_ARGS__` to represent undefined number of parameter values. You can do:

```
#define TRACE1(str, ...) TRACE2(str,__VA_ARGS__)  // call TRACE2 to do the same
// or simply
#define TRACE1  TRACE2                          // TRACE1 is TRACE2
// but to keep TRACE1 same syntax ignoring the 1st parameter it is
#define TRACE1(dummy,str, ...) TRACE2(str,__VA_ARGS__)
```